# Having trouble assigning strings from a file to an array of string

Tags: c, arrays, string, file, memory

The assignment is to read words from a text file, then print them in reverse to another text file. I'm having trouble with putting the words I read in to an array. I am not supposed to allocate any more memory than necessary to hold each string, so the only solution I could think of was putting each word in tempString, measuring its length, then allocating enough memory to hold it and moving to the next word. My confusion is why for each iteration every word in the array is changed. I'd expect the last line to be fivefourthreetwoone.

I also think my method is kind of sloppy because having a string longer than the length of tempString would cause a problem, but I can't think of a solution to this either.

Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/*
 * 
 */

char** readWords(int* nPtr);

int main() {
    int numWords = 0;

    readWords(&numWords);

    return 0;
}



char** readWords(int* nPtr){
    int i = 0;
    int listIndex = 0;
    char tempChar = 0;
    char** stringArray = NULL;
    char tempString[50] = {};

    FILE *inputfile=fopen("inputfile.txt","r");
    fscanf(inputfile,"%d\n",nPtr); //Makes numWords = integer on first line

    stringArray = calloc(*nPtr, sizeof(char*));

    for(i=0;i<*nPtr;i++){
        fscanf(inputfile,"%s", tempString);
        stringArray[*nPtr-1-i] = calloc(strlen(tempString)+1, sizeof(char));
        stringArray[*nPtr-1-i] = tempString;
        printf("tempString: %s\n",tempString);
        printf("stringArray index: %d\n",*nPtr-1-i);
        printf("stringArray: %s%s%s%s%s\n",stringArray[0],stringArray[1],stringArray[2],stringArray[3],stringArray[4]);
    }


    fclose(inputfile);

}
```

Here is my output

```
tempString: one
stringArray index: 4
stringArray: (null)(null)(null)(null)one
tempString: two
stringArray index: 3
stringArray: (null)(null)(null)twotwo
tempString: three
stringArray index: 2
stringArray: (null)(null)threethreethree
tempString: four
stringArray index: 1
stringArray: (null)fourfourfourfour
tempString: five
stringArray index: 0
stringArray: fivefivefivefivefive

RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 64ms)
```

Here is my input file

```
5
one
two
three
four
five
```

Advice is very much appreciated

Comment: You forget to copy the temporary string into the space you've allocated for it in the array.

Comment: There are a number of things wrong in this code. The most dreadful being anytime you see `ptr = some-allocation-function(...);` followed by `ptr = something else;` you just (a) copied an address; not a block of memory, and (b) leaked memory in two short lines (only one more than the record; a bare `malloc` with no assignment). The quick-fix is a `strcpy` rather than an assignment, but this code honestly needs a little more help than that.

Comment: Thanks, I used strcpy and it works now. It didn't fully occur to me that strings are pointers in c rather than datatypes. Would you mind listing some of the other things wrong in my code? I don't know what you mean by (b). Doesn't calloc initialize the memory to null? What do you mean by no assignment. I'm very new to dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: Hardly took much time to look closely, but [something like this](http://pastebin.com/GjJpTrL4). Note the coupling of the array with its length in a structure to keep things that are related tight. There's other topics in there, dynamic expansion of the pointer array, etc. I turned it loose on the BSD dictionary file (230K+ words) and it plowed through without effort, so hopefully it helps. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In effect ALL array element are being assigned the tempString value, so they all point to the SAME place holder, which therefor at the end they all point to the LAST value being stored into tempString. The fix is to copy the content of tempString into the allocated place holder of the respective array element:

```
strcpy( stringArray[*nPtr-1-i], tempString );
```

Comment: @user3620725 : If Ron's answer sufficiently answered your question, it is generally a good idea to accept the answer. More on accepting answers can be found [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/271768)

Comment: @user3620725 - while there is nothing wrong with `fscanf`, you may find that `getline` is superior for line input due to it returning the number of characters read **and** being able to dynamically allocate memory as needed when `**lineptr` is set to `NULL`. see `man getline` -- definitely worth a look.